# Ubuntu 20.04 GTX1080ti performance issues

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, cuda

I just updated my PC/rig to ubuntu 20.04 and driver (390, 435 and 440 tested) from ubuntu repo if i set lower power limit clock drop from 50-70% (depending on cuda miner use)…
clock drop under 16.04 was from 10-30% but here power use is huge and performance drop way more
power limit of 160w drop clock to ~500-600Mhz while mining and in ubuntu 16.04 clock drop only to ~1300Mhz

tried updating kernel, setting performance mode all the same, same rigs on gtx 1070 works fine and appz is hashing ~14Mhs at 110W and Gtx 1080ti 160W is doing 11Mhs

| NVIDIA-SMI 440.64 Driver Version: 440.64 CUDA Version: 10.2 |

| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |

| 0 GeForce GTX 108… On | 00000000:01:00.0 On | N/A |
| 80% 61C P2 163W / 160W | 2654MiB / 11178MiB | 100% Default |

| 1 GeForce GTX 108… On | 00000000:02:00.0 On | N/A |
| 80% 60C P2 163W / 160W | 2580MiB / 11178MiB | 100% Default |

| 2 GeForce GTX 108… On | 00000000:03:00.0 On | N/A |
| 80% 56C P2 102W / 160W | 2580MiB / 11178MiB | 100% Default |

| 3 GeForce GTX 108… On | 00000000:05:00.0 On | N/A |
| 80% 58C P2 163W / 160W | 2580MiB / 11178MiB | 100% Default |

nvidia-smi -i 0,1,2,3,4 --format=csv --query-gpu=clocks.mem,clocks.gr
clocks.current.memory [MHz], clocks.current.graphics [MHz]
5514 MHz, 658 MHz
5514 MHz, 658 MHz
5400 MHz, 544 MHz
5514 MHz, 683 MHz

ADD:
I did more digging and as soon i start GPU cude appz Sw power cap change to active:

SW Power Cap : Active

Comment: Its usual practice to do it while mining as it drop voltage for GPU, gtx1070 on ubuntu 20.04 works fine have no issue with huge clock drop, command is
sudo nvidia-smi -i 0,1,2,3 -pl 160